# having server error after some of the pages after installing laravel 5.8 on the live server

Tags: laravel

Everything is working perfectly on my localhost server but after I upload everything on the live server, some of the pages are having a "Server Error". some of them this page,

[image]

public_html .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/public .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Public_html/storage/logs

```
[2019-12-24 18:42:01] local.ERROR: proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): proc_open(): fork failed - Resource temporarily unavailable at /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php:127)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', '/home/customer/...', 127, Array)
#1 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(127): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(70): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Terminal::getSttyColumns()
#3 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(51): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Terminal::initDimensions()
#4 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(116): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Terminal->getHeight()
#5 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /home/customer/www/aftscredit.com/public_html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Nothing in the log? `.env`  set up?

Comment: some times PHP version issue occur. Check PHP Version

Comment: Hi @kerbholz I just update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Requirements for Installing Laravel 5.8
Before installing 5.8, you need to make sure you are working on a Laravel Homestead virtual machine as it fulfills all the critical system requirements. If you are not using Homestead, your server should fulfill the following requirements:

```
1. PHP: 7.1.3 or greater
2. PDO PHP extension
3. JSON PHP extension
4. OpenSSL PHP extension
5. Tokenizer PHP extension
6. XML PHP extension
7. Mbstring PHP extension
8. Ctype PHP extension
9. BCMath PHP extension
```

Comment: Thanks I just send these to my shared server. I hope this work

Comment: It's my pleasure @Lito